# Meaning of prefix length with ip addr add noprefixroute

Tags: networking, iproute, ip-address

When assigning an ip address to a network interface with `ip addr add noprefixroute`, what effect will the specified prefix length have? When `noprefixroute` is not used, the prefix length is used to automatically create and delete a route for the network prefix of the added address. Does it have any function other than that?

For example, what is the difference between

```
ip addr add noprefixroute 10.137.0.36/16 dev eth0
```

and

```
ip addr add noprefixroute 10.137.0.36/32 dev eth0
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed there doesn't appear to be much useful difference, but there's at least one: the way a secondary address is handled won't change, whether a route is added or not.

When a 2nd address is added to the same interface as an other address with the same netmask within the same network, it's classified as a *secondary address*. When the first address (primary, without the *secondary* property) is removed, all other matching addresses in the same IP LAN, all *secondaries*, are also removed.

Example:

- from scratch:

  ```shell
  # ip addr flush dev eth0
  ```
- add the main address (the first):

  ```shell
  # ip addr add noprefixroute 10.137.0.36/16 dev eth0
  ```
- add an other address within the same IP LAN, using the same netmask

  ```shell
  # ip addr add noprefixroute 10.137.0.42/16 dev eth0
  ```
- check current state

  ```shell
  # ip route
  # ip addr show dev eth0
  2: eth0@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 0e:00:00:74:02:fd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
      inet 10.137.0.36/16 scope global noprefixroute eth0
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
      inet 10.137.0.42/16 scope global secondary noprefixroute eth0
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  ```
- remove primary (first) and witness 2nd gone too

  ```shell
  # ip addr del 10.137.0.36/16 dev eth0
  # ip addr show dev eth0
  2: eth0@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 0e:00:00:74:02:fd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
  ```

This wouldn't have happened with two /32 because they would both be considered primary addresses (Using /32 they are not part of the same IP LAN). By the way, there's a parameter to promote a secondary as primary instead of deleting all secondaries: [`promote_secondaries`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v6.6#n1881).

Conclusion: `noprefixroute` affects creation of routes, but not other properties linked to addresses.

I don't know if there are more visible differences. Maybe something can be found with ARP when settings such as [`arp_ignore`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v6.6#n1788) or [`arp_announce`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v6.6#n1756) are changed from their permissive default: unlike [`arp_filter`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v6.6#n1737) their description is about addresses, not routes.

Comment: You should also check this Q/A where the answer addresses a more common difference (use of broadcast) than the one I mentioned here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/769210/how-exactly-does-linux-use-the-prefix-length-assigned-to-network-interface