# What is a sane config for P2P DHCP using busybox udhcpd?

Tags: linux, dhcp, udhcpc

I have two computers connected directly via ethernet with one serving as a dhcp server and the other as a client
my config:

```
interface   eth0
lease_file  /var/lib/udhcpd/udhcpd.leases
remaining   no

start   192.168.1.2
end 192.168.1.16

option dns  9.9.9.9
option dns  192.168.1.1
option subnet   255.255.255.255
option router   192.168.1.1
option domain   local
option lease    864000
```

the options I have mixed and matched and even tried to go without, but the results are mostly the same: I still have to manually add a route on both machenes manually.
my expected behaviour is that udhcpd is running on PC_0 and udhcpc on PC_1, PC_1 gets an address and route from PC_0 via dhcp and I can ping one from the other and vice versa.
that's not what hapens though, as I still need to `ip route add remote_ip/subnet_mask via local_ip dev eth0` whenever I connect them. I also have to manually asign an IP address on PC_0 that runs udhcpd. how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified:

> ```
> option subnet   255.255.255.255
> ```

which means when the client creates an address, it will have /255.255.255.255 netmask , aka /32 in CIDR notation. How many hosts are in a LAN where for example 192.168.1.10/32 was leased? There's [only one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#IPv4_CIDR_blocks). With one host, there's no route to add to reach such LAN: that's why the Linux kernel won't add an automatic LAN route (typically seen back with the command `ip route` as `proto kernel scope link`).

Fix this by issuing a wider netmask that will allow to encompass all of the range from 192.168.1.1 (the router has the lowest address here) to 192.168.1.16 (end of range: highest address) included. /28 would be between 192.168.1.0 and 192.168.1.15: not enough. So /27 <=> 255.255.255.224 is good enough, or you can choose up to the usual /24 (255.255.255.0) instead. Anything wider is at risk of colliding with something else, considering chances are the DHCP server is also acting as router to Internet (eg: to reach the DNS server at 9.9.9.9), even if this information is not disclosed here, so has an other side. This solves the DHCP client configuration.

As for the server side, it's supposed to be configured with a matching netmask: so with 192.168.1.1 plus the same netmask as chosen above, between 192.168.1.1/27 and 192.168.1.1/24. Same will happen: the kernel will add automatically a route of type `proto kernel` for the LAN with such address configured.

Comment: intresting that manually assigning a mask of /32 works just fine, why would that be? if it isn't obvious I don't really know much about networking. P.S. why would it not work if I didn't specify subnet I.E. omitting the line you quoted? it finally works as expected after making the suggested changes

Comment: /32 can be used to manually add a route as you did instead of letting the kernel do it. This could also affect the use of broadcasts (Q/A: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/769210/how-exactly-does-linux-use-the-prefix-length-assigned-to-network-interface ). Or it is required (for some routing reason: to avoid "owning" all the LAN by the host instead) if adding a global address to the `lo` interface. Then on Linux you can replace part of the /32 logic by using `noprefixroute` (Q/A: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/768760/meaning-of-prefix-length-with-ip-addr-add-noprefixroute ).